# How to log in on Windows 8 Pro when no log in field is displayed?

Tags: windows-8

I have the following problem:

I've been using Windows 8 PRO for a few months and everything has been OK, but starting a few days ago I can not log in.  It happens when the system locks my screen after a period of inactivity.

The usual lock screen appears. Normally when I click it a text field appears where I can enter my password. However, once a day at random there is no place to enter my password and no user image. I can still move the mouse and the PC seems to not be frozen, but I can not log in.

How can I find the reason for this problem?

Comment: "once a day"? You mean to say the error only occurs once every day, at random?

Comment: @Karan yes, it is random.

Comment: have you tried ctrl+alt+del ?

Comment: Check the system event log, though I'm not sure it'll help. Maybe enable remote desktop (since it's Pro, it can do that) and then use a different PC to connect to it and see if that works, once it "Locks". Finally, use something like psexec to reboot it remotely if nothing else.